# how can i count the number of times a string appears in my dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count, dataset

Here is the dataframe I would like to work on:

```
df = data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "red"), col_2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5))
```

In this dataframe appears in each row the name of a color, and the number corresponding to its appearance (for example "red" appears 5 times, so in the dataframe we have 5 line with the color "red", and each time the number of its appearance in the dataframe)

I would like to create a new dataframe in which:
in the first column appears the color name, and in the second column appears the number of times that color appears in the first dataframe.

So, in my new dataframe, each row corresponds to a unique color, and the number of times it appeared in the first dataframe. (in this dataframe there is only 2 colors, but in the real dataframe there is a lot of colors. Here it's just for example)

could someone help me please ?

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(df[,"color"]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(table(df$color))
```

Returns:

> ```
>   Var1 Freq
> 1 blue    3
> 2  red    5
> ```

Or, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  count()
```

Returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
> # Groups:   color [2]
>   color     n
>   <chr> <int>
> 1 blue      3
> 2 red       5
> ```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[, .(count = .N),  by = color]
```

Returns:

> ```
>    color count
> 1:   red     5
> 2:  blue     3
> ```

Comment: `as.character(df[order(-df$Freq), ][1,1])`

Answer (score 0):

First get the unique colors :

```
the_colors <- unique(df$color)
```

Then get the count :

```
the_count <- sapply(the_colors, function(x) sum(df$color == x))
```

Now create the `data.frame` :

```
new_df = data.frame(colors=the_colors, count=the_count)
```

Here's the output :

> ```
> > new_df
>   colors count
> 1    red     5
> 2   blue     3
> ```